"てになるし" what kind of grammar is this?
「もちろん着地はお前みたいには出来ないよ？マットを引いてになるし、どうしてもワンストップにはならないけど―絶対うまく真似してみせるから！
The character is a stunt. He's commenting on someone else's 着地 stunt. As far I understand, he's saying that he can't do  landing like the other person, because he will get caught by the mat and won't be able to "stop" with one move. Still, he wants to make a cool imitation of it.
What I'm curios is, whats' 引いてになるし here? At least I assume 引いてhere is the verb in て form

Maybe it has to do with ての?

Yes, it's the te-form of 引く. A te-form sometimes works like a no-adjective to express a precondition or the action that comes first.

開けて(から)のお楽しみだ。
You'll see when you open it. / The fun begins after you open it.

音楽(が)あっての私です。
Music is what makes me who I am. (cf. How is あっての used to define something?)

知っててだったんですか？
So you did it knowingly?

受験するならまず勉強して(から)だ。
If you're taking the exam, you need to study first.

誰かがいてくれてなら大丈夫ですが、一人では無理です。
I'll be fine if someone is with me, but I can't do it alone.

マットを引いて(から)になる。
I need to lay out the mat first.


This 引く means "to install (cables); to set up; to lay out".
